# Bootstrap 4 checkbox/switch control - how to be small (-sm)?

Tags: css, forms, bootstrap-4

Using BS4 the custom switch/checkbox can be added to the form. Unfortunately - the small (-sm) modification wont work. I attach a code sample and an image.

[image: Current output] https://www.codeply.com/p/gZuRjGvqG2

What I want to achieve is to get the switch become as small (in height) as the input field itself. I cannot find "custom-control-sm" or similar class, and **form-control-sm** wont work.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
 <span class="input-group-prepend">
  <span class="input-group-text">
   <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
  </span>
 </span>
 <span class="input-group-prepend">
  <span class="input-group-text">
   <span class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input form-control-sm" aria-autocomplete="none" autocomplete="off" id="DefineAttributes" name="DefineAttributes" title="Define the attributes" value="true">
    <label class="custom-control-label form-control-sm" for="DefineAttributes"></label>
   </span>
  </span>
 </span>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-autocomplete="none" autocomplete="off" id="Attributes" name="Attributes" placeholder="Attributes ..." value="something">
 <span class="input-group-append">
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary " title="Select attributes" href="#">Select</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to do the following changes:

1. Add `p-0` to `<span class="input-group-text">` (the one for the checkbox).
2. Add `"style=height: 0;"` to `<input type="checkbox" ...` & `<label class="custom-control-label ...` to remove any height the invisible element has.
3. Adjust the position of the resultant slider with custom margins on the `<span class="custom-control custom-switch">`, i.e., added: `"style="margin-left: 24px; margin-right: -12px;"`

This should result in a proper looking slider, and in the `sm` size.

Comment: Nasty tricks indeed - but do the job. Thanks for you time! And it calms me down that its not my lack of knowledge, but a hole in the BS4 system that sm sized checkboxes/switches are simple missing... thanks!

Comment: Yes this problem occurs with the switches, using a normal checkbox works fine out of the box!